# AWS IAM multiple policies with conflicting conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

It is weird that I could find no docs on this; maybe I'm not googling right. I see nothing about conditions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html

I have two questions:

- I have two policies applied to the same entity for the same resource

One looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "secretsmanager:ResourceTag/allow": "True"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And one looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "secretsmanager:ResourceTag/allow": "False"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Which one wins? I don't think you can order policies. How does AWS merge the conditions?

- My other question: I have one policy that has a condition and one does not. Both are attached to the same entity and target the same resources

One policy allows access to all resources with no conditions like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

One policy has a condition:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "secretsmanager:ResourceTag/allow": "True"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Will the entity be allowed access to resources not tagged with `Allow:True` or will the condition of one of the policies block it?

Comment: As far as i know Deny/Block wins over the allow if they are attached to the same entity. This doc seems to be relevant https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html#reference_policies_multiple-conditions-eval

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, let me answer the question directly.  This is logically what IAM is doing.

1. Evaluate all the identity policy statements.
2. Do any Deny policy statements evaluate to True.  If so deny the request.
3. Do any of the Allow policy statements evaluate to True.  If so accept the request
4. Deny the request because there is no allow statement that evaluated to true.

For use case 1 above:

1. If tag "allow" is set the user is allowed. This is because 1 or both of the statements will always be true.
2. If the tag "allow" is not set then the user is denied.  This is because neither statement will be true.

To only allow the user access if tag "allow" is set to true you need the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "secretsmanager:ResourceTag/allow": "True"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Use case #2 above:

The user will always be granted access because of the first policy statement is always true.

Now what if only want to allow access if and only if the tag "allow" is set to true.  You need to explicitly deny when it is not true.:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "secretsmanager:ResourceTag/allow": "True"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "secretsmanager:ResourceTag/allow": "True"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This time we ad an explicit deny policy to guarantee that the "allow" tag is set.

Now for a little more information in the wonders of IAM.

There are 11 decision points in [AWS IAM Policy Evaluation Logic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html).  6 paths to deny and only 2 to allow.  But this graph should help you figure it.

[image]

In the case of [multiple statements in the condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html) multiple statements are "boolean and" and multi values are "boolean or".

[image]

Comment: that says nothing about how conflicting conditions are merged

Comment: Conditions are not merged, they are evaluated using boolean logic.  I've updated my answer to explain multiple conditional statements.    I'll be able to answer where question if you include the complete policy statements with the effect statements.

Comment: ill add to my question the actions and everything

Comment: I updated my question with full policy examples. It would be awesome if you could help me determine what the behavior would be

Comment: Thank you for the details, that helped. I updated my answer.   I think what you are looking for is my 2nd policy with an Allow and Deny statement.  Note the changes I make the StringNotLike and StringLike in relation to the Allow and Deny.